# How to keep text to a texbox that binds data from a database after Postback

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Below is one of the template field that composes a gridview. All of the value of the label and textboxes are from a database, and I want to focus on this specific textbox, here is the aspx code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ServiceStart" SortExpression="ServiceStart">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="txtEditServiceStart" runat="server" type="date" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceStart","{0:d}") %>'  Width="128px"></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="LblItemServiceStart" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("ServiceStart","{0:d}") %>' ></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Note that txtEditServiceStart is type=date

when the program runs here is the initial look:

Picture 1
[image: Picture 1]

Now, when the user clicks the Edit, to edit the said date of textbox(txtEditServiceStart),the textbox looks like this:

Picture 2
[image: Picture 2]

it shows: mm/dd/yyyy and does not show the record from the database.

**BUT** when the user **DID NOT** change the value of that textbox and clicks: **UPDATE**(to basically to save changes), it will load the gridview again, and problem is it DOES'NT keeps the date of the textbox instead it will default to:   1/1/1900. Where it should show the data like from the Picture 1 **again**

Note that there is no problem when the user did edit the date, it will just update the database and gridview will show the new value/date.

> Basically, I just need to show the data again to the gridview if its
>   not edited by the user instead of showing 1/1/1900

I've tried using the  `txtEditServiceStart.Attributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");` but it wont recognize my textbox on the c# code,  i think it's because I *Bind* data from a database, perhaps the program wont run.
I've also tried using Eval, instead of Bind but still not working

EDIT: Here is how I put data on the grid

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        BindGrid();
    }
}

public void BindGrid()
{
    SQLConnect.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    SQLConnect.Open();
    string sql = "Select  LastName+', '+FirstName+' '+MiddleName  AS EmployeeName, EMPLOYEE.EmpID, ContractNo, ContractDate, ContractDuration, ServiceStart, ContractDetails, ContractValue, Served from EMPLOYEE join SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT ON EMPLOYEE.EmpID = SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT.EmpID";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, SQLConnect);
    SqlDataAdapter GridDA = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataSet GridDS = new DataSet();
    GridDA.Fill(GridDS);
    //Bind data to gridview
    GridView1.DataSource = GridDS;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    //close connection
    cmd.Dispose();
    SQLConnect.Close();
```

Here is how the edit, cancel edit, update's code:

```
protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "EditRow")
    {
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;
        GridView1.EditIndex = rowIndex;

        BindGrid();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "CancelUpdate")
    {
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();
    }
    else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow")
    {
        int rowIndex = ((GridViewRow)((LinkButton)e.CommandSource).NamingContainer).RowIndex;

        string ContractNo = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditContractNo")).Text;
        string contractDate = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditContractDate")).Text;  
        string contractDuration = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditContractDuration")).Text;
        string serviceStart = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditServiceStart")).Text;
        string contractDetails = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditContractDetails")).Text;
        string contractValue = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditContractValue")).Text;
        string DropDownServed = ((DropDownList)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("DropDownServed")).Text;

        AccessLayer.UpdateContract(ContractNo, contractDate, contractDuration, serviceStart, contractDetails, contractValue, DropDownServed);
        GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
        BindGrid();

    }
}
```

AccessLayer = update contract:

```
public static int UpdateContract(string ContractNo, string ContractDate, string ContractDuration, string ServiceStart, string ContractDetails, string ContractValue, string Served)
{
    string css = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(css))
    {
        string UpdateQuery = "UPDATE SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT SET ContractDate= @ContractDate, ContractDuration = @ContractDuration, ServiceStart = @ServiceStart, ContractDetails = @ContractDetails, ContractValue= @ContractValue, Served = @Served WHERE ContractNo =@ContractNo";
        SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, con);

        SqlParameter paramOriginalContractNo = new SqlParameter("ContractNo", ContractNo);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramOriginalContractNo);
        SqlParameter paramContractDate = new SqlParameter("@ContractDate", ContractDate);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramContractDate);
        SqlParameter paramContractDuration = new SqlParameter("@ContractDuration", ContractDuration);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramContractDuration);
        SqlParameter paramServiceStart = new SqlParameter("@ServiceStart", ServiceStart);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramServiceStart);
        SqlParameter paramContractDetails = new SqlParameter("@ContractDetails", ContractDetails);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramContractDetails);
        SqlParameter paramContractValue = new SqlParameter("@ContractValue", ContractValue);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramContractValue);
        SqlParameter paramServed = new SqlParameter("@Served", Served);
        UpdateCmd.Parameters.Add(paramServed);
        con.Open();
        return UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Please suggest a way/method that i can add on the aspx or c# code thank you

Comment: After UPDATE date is 1/1/1900 also in db?

Comment: I suspect that you are binding the grid on `page_load`. can you share some of your code please? or make sure that you do the `bind` `if !Page.IsPostback`

Comment: @mwisnicki that's right, the 1/1/1900 also in db

Comment: Can you put your code, show how you update this data. I think the problem is with your update method.

Comment: @Ted You're right, here is a mini code: `protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindGrid();}`

Comment: @mwisnicki sure, I'll update the question now thanks

Comment: Its updated now, thanks

Comment: So you get date from textbox like string, show also AccessLayer.UpdateContract() method and format datetime which you try update.

Comment: @mwisnicki sure ill update it again, and what do you mean by "format datetime which you try update"

Comment: Just show sample of contractDate string.

Comment: its now updated, the contractDate/serviceStart only dates like: 2015/1/2 , datatype in database is : Date

Comment: have tried without formatting date and set to service start date column `Text='<%# Bind("ServiceStart") %>'`

Comment: @JaydipJ yeah...same problem..

Comment: I have doubt on format which you use try to set format like this `yyyy-MM-dd` this may solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is  you always update your `ContractDate`. You have to edit query string. Add `COALESCE` will assign a value to ContractDate that is: `@ContractDate` if it was populated, otherwise it assigns the existing value of `ContractDate`. Change type of ContractDate in method to `?DateTime` it allow you put into method `null`. When you call method just check textbox if date was edited  put it in method if not set null.

```
 public static int UpdateContract(string ContractNo, DateTime? ContractDate, string ContractDuration, string ServiceStart, string ContractDetails, string ContractValue, string Served)
    {
        string css = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["dbx"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(css))
        {
            string UpdateQuery = "UPDATE SCHOLARSHIPCONTRACT SET ContractDate=COALESCE(@ContractDate=ContractDate), ContractDuration = @ContractDuration, ServiceStart = @ServiceStart, ContractDetails = @ContractDetails, ContractValue= @ContractValue, Served = @Served WHERE ContractNo =@ContractNo";
            SqlCommand UpdateCmd = new SqlCommand(UpdateQuery, con);


            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ContractNo", ContractNo);
            //Here you have to convert string to DateTime
            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractDate", ContractDate);
            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractDuration", ContractDuration);
            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ServiceStart", ServiceStart);
            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractDetails", ContractDetails);
            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContractValue", ContractValue);
            UpdateCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Served", Served);

            con.Open();
            return UpdateCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
```

Comment: My apologies, im wrong on the first description of the problem. Please look at my question again, I did updated it with pictures. Basically, I just need to show the data again to the gridview if its not edited by the user instead of showing 1/1/1900. I hope you may help me, thank you~

Comment: need to remove extra equal to sign from `ContractDate==COALESCE`

Comment: ive updated the AccessLayer Update Contract, now in the GridView1_RowCommand: else if (e.CommandName == "UpdateRow"), ive changed it from string to DateTime `DateTime contractDate = ((TextBox)GridView1.Rows[rowIndex].FindControl("txtEditContractDate")).Text;` and its giving me error: Cannot implicitly convert type string to System.DateTime.  I think its because i declare it string in the BindGrid() ?? any ideas thanks

Comment: Can you guys please suggest other way to call the SQL statement without using the `string sql = "Select ...` , please note that the query has JOIN statements so that I can call ContractDate as DateTime. Or do you have other suggestions thanks

Comment: I replaced string to var in declaring the SQL query to bind data. Can you give me idea how to convert  string to DateTime as said on the answer ^ thanks